# program that print larger numbers

Tags: c++

`$`it was supposed to print all the numbers that are larger than 80 from 5 numbers.
But the program that I write just print the 1st number that are larger than 80.
How can I make it to print all the numbers that are larger than 80?
Here is my code..

```
int main ()
{

    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5;

    cout << "Enter five marks : ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4 >> num5;
    cout << endl;


         cout << "Marks are greater than 80 is : ";

         {
         if (num1 > 80)
         cout << num1 << endl;

         else if(num2 > 80)
         cout << num2 << endl;

         else if(num3 > 80)
         cout << num3 << endl;

         else if(num4 > 80)
         cout << num4 << endl;

         else if(num5 > 80)
         cout << num5 << endl;

         else
         cout << "error" << endl;
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those `else` from your conditions.

```
if (num1 > 80)
    cout << num1 << endl;

if(num2 > 80)
    cout << num2 << endl;

if(num3 > 80)
    cout << num3 << endl;

if(num4 > 80)
    cout << num4 << endl;

if(num5 > 80)
    cout << num5 << endl;
```

Also you can use loop since you're doing same things:

```
int num[5];

cout << "Enter five marks : ";
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    cin >> num[i];

cout << "Marks are greater than 80 is : ";

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    if (num[i]>80)
        cout << num[i] << endl;
```

---

I can't understand your last `else cout << "error" << endl;`. Maybe you want to warn the user to enter at least one number greater that eighty? Then you can try this:

```
bool flag = false;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    if (num[i]>80)
    {
        cout << num[i] << endl;
        flag = true;
    }

if (flag)
   cout << "Error" << endl;
```

Comment: Side comment: if you had indented your code correctly, it would have been a lot easier to see the problem.

Comment: You could also use `int numbers[5]; for (int& num : numbers) std::cin >> num;` etc. so you don't have to hardcode the umber 5 everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

replace `else if` with `if`. When you use an `else if` chain, only one of them will be executed (the first one which matches).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is using `if`, then continuing with `else if`. That makes all of your conditions exclusive to each other, meaning only *one* of them is going to occur.

Remove the `else` part to make them inclusive.

```
if (num1 > 80)
 cout << num1 << endl;

if(num2 > 80)
 cout << num2 << endl;

// etc.
```

You'll also probably want to remove your `else` block, or create a condition that checks if all numbers are `<= 80` and error if that's true.

```
if (num1 <= 80 && num2 <= 80 && num3 <= 80 && num4 <= 80 && num5 <= 80) {
    cout << "error" << endl;
}
```